# iOS TableView drilldown freeze

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, uitableview

Alright this is what I have so far in my application, the main view which has a tableview with different tasks. When you touch one it pushes to the DetailViewController. I have been trying to make an internal tableview in the detailview. So I have a TableController up now but now when I click a task it just freezes.

**Update Added Code:**

```
//RootViewController
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize toolbar;
@synthesize window;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    theArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Kill Taylor",@"Stab Taylor",@"Pay Jordan",nil];
    //theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    [super viewDidLoad];

    addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
   // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //return UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    return UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
}

-(void) addButtonPressed
{
    NSString *selectedAction = @"add";


    DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    dvController.selectedAction = selectedAction;
    //dvController.selectedTask = selectedTask;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}

/*
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
*/

/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
 */



// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [theArray count];

}



// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    return cell;

}
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (editing)
    {
        // turn on the "add" button when editing
        //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    }
    else
    {
        // remove the "add" butto when not editing
        //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    }

     [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
*/


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/


/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *selectedAction = @"details";
    NSString *selectedTask = [theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    dvController.selectedAction = selectedAction;
    dvController.selectedTask = selectedTask;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

The above all works

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"


@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize selectedTask;
@synthesize selectedAction;
// The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    if(selectedAction == @"details"){
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Task Details";
        //lblText.text = selectedTask;
    }
    else if(selectedAction == @"add"){
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Add Task";
        //lblText.text = selectedTask;

    }
}


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [selectedTask release];
    [lblText release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

This does not work if it has any stuff that build the inside table.

Comment: does the app crash or just stop responding? Can you set a breakpoint on tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and step through what happens post-click?

Comment: perhaps you are entering into a infinite loop? Without errors or code we cannot do more than guessing

Comment: Could you tell us where your Apps got freeze whether in Controller which show the task list OR in Details controller (Point of freeze in Apps)..One guess-- may be you are passing the invalid data to detail controller.

Comment: why you always do this - " dvController = nil;" ????

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be in your viewDidLoad method in DetailedViewController. Fix the following two things and see if that makes a difference.

- Move your [super viewDidLoad] so out of your if conditional.
- Compare string in the right ways using the isEqualToString: method

Here's your code, tweaked:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      [super viewDidLoad];

      if(selectedAction isEqualToString: @"details")
      {
           self.navigationItem.title = @"Task Details";
           //lblText.text = selectedTask;
     }
else if (selectedAction isEqualToString: @"add")
     {
          self.navigationItem.title = @"Add Task";
          //lblText.text = selectedTask;
    }
}
```